# manipulate output from file using awk

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have file in unix

```
a,b,c,d
e,f,g,h
u,v,x,y
```

and i want to print the first col and every other col with it seperatly

ie

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
e,f
e,g
e,h
```

etc.

thanks in advance

Comment: What did you try for yourself? _and_ why is there a `,` after `e,g` record?

Comment: because I am having trouble, why else would i ask the question, and because it was a trivial typo

Comment: @AbBennett yes it is understood that you asked the question because you were stuck with the problem... but SO is about getting help with code you've already tried, not about asking entire code...

Comment: @AbBennett: Glad you found an answer to your probem, but beware of this attitude in StackOverflow! people generally look at the history of questions a person has asked before checking for their efforts done asking it. And if the same type of behavior repeats, i.e. asking questions of similar nature without showing efforts, your post will likely get downvoted and will not not attract much answers. "my 2¢"

Comment: @AbBennett you could at least have put one of the awk command you tried... `its a one line command` then why couldn't you do it? it takes plenty of learning to arrive at the solution... `i just needed a quick answer` then ask elsewhere... SO is not the right forum

Comment: #there did it in python so you dont think i am lazy{f = open(l_write_file, 'w')
   f.write("TranId,ItemId\n")
   for k,v in G_FILE_RAW_DATA.items():
      for k2,v2 in v.items():
         if k2!="Date":
            #print (str(v["Date"])+","+str(v[k2]))
            f.write(str(v["Date"])+","+str(v[k2])+"\n")
   f.close()
   fSleep(1,'Written file '+l_write_file,True)

Comment: If you put that in your question instead of as a comment and delete your `just shut up and give me my answer` comments then it will stop the deluge of downvotes you're going to get.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a zero-effort requirements dump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done with this perl one-liner

```
perl -F, -anle '$first=shift@F;print"$first,$_"for@F' <input.txt
```

How it works:

To understand switches just type `perl -h`

- `-a` combined with `-F,` : splits (default variable) input with `,` into (array for autosplit) `@F`
- `-n` : loop over lines
- `-l` : line processing chomp end of line and add newline after print
- `-e` : inline program

For information on special variables and functions see `perldoc perlvar` and `perldoc perlfun`

- shift : remove element in front of an array

Comment: thanks, perfect answer

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest trying to get started on [GAWK: Effective AWK Programming by Arnold D. Robbins](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.pdf) if you are looking to face such problems in the future.

---

As for the answer, it is pretty straight-forward in `Awk`!

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file
```

produces an output as you need.

```
a,b
a,c
a,d
e,f
e,g
e,h
u,v
u,x
u,y
```

`Awk` works by processing input lines *one* at a time. And there are special clauses which `Awk` provides, `BEGIN{}` and `END{}` which encloses actions to be run before and after the processing of the file.

So the part `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` is set before the file processing happens, and `FS` and `OFS` are special variables in `Awk` which stand for input and output field separators. Since you have a provided a file that is de-limited by `,` you need to parse it by setting `FS=","` also to print it back in `.csv` format you need to set `OFS=","`

The main part of the command comes after `BEGIN` clause, which has a for-loop that loops till the max number of fields in the *current* line (here `NF` value is 4). Once the appropriate de-limiter is set, you can access individual fields by `$1`,`$2`..`$NF`.

The loop I have starts at `$2` i.e. starting from the 2<sup>nd</sup> de-limited record to the last record and the action part of the loop is to print the 1<sup>st</sup> field and whatever field encountered in the loop denoted by `$i`. Each `print` action prints the values in a new-line. So as you progress through the loop you can print the fields as expected.